# iPad UITableView Reload Slow

Tags: ios

In single screen I have added UITableview and UICollectionview. I have added default delegate and datasource methods for both TableView and Collection View. but UITableView only little slow to load data. That data I have added statically that too load very slowly. Same code working fast in iPhone but iPad I am facing this slowness issues. Anyone know about this please help me do this.

Comment: what is the iPad and iPhone version which you have used for testing?

Comment: did you check the memory?

Comment: iPad - 9.3.5, iPhone - 11.0, Is there any auto layout problem will happen in iPad.

Comment: Auto Layout I am using is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for that, Actually in my tableviewcellforrowatindexpath function i made some changes .

My current code following as,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellId = @"SimpleTableId";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             cellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             cellId];
    if (cell1 == nil) {
        cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

     UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             cellId];
    if (cell2 == nil) {
        cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

   if(values == 1)
   {

       return cell;

   }
    else if(values == 2)
{

    return cell1;


}
else
{

    return cell;

    }
}
```

I have changed like below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellId = @"SimpleTableId";

    if(values == 1)
    {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             cellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }


    return cell;
    }
    else if(values == 2)
    {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             cellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }


    return cell;
    }
    else
    {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             cellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }


    return cell;
    }

}
```

Now my slowness issues solved as much expected.